# HTML ignoring container class for specific tags

Tags: html, css

I have a container class in my css file that looks like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

My aim is to place a video in the container class to span the full width of the page (i.e. basically ignoring the borders).

My video tag looks like this:

```html
<video class="promo" autoplay><source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='media/vid.mp4') }}"></video>
```

The css block for this class looks as such:

```css
body .promo {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Right now the video looks like this:
[image: the goal]
I have illustrated what I am trying to achieve with MS paint :)

Any help is appreciated

### Edit:

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HWnJDSAKwXqrVhQBCCfsJp3-f71czhMa?usp=sharing) is a link to a reproducible example. You will need to install `Flask`.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: If I get it right, your `.promo` is within an element with a class of `.container`, whose `width` is defined as `1200px`? As long as an element (`.promo`) has a position of `static` (default) or relative, it will always behave relative to its parent, this means, if it has a `width` of `100%`, it will span the 100% of width of its parent (`.container`) = `1200px`

Comment: That is correct. Whereabouts would I place `<video>` element to prevent it from inheriting the parent properties (which is the maximum width of 1200px)?

Comment: You could simply increase the size of the parent (set it to `100vw` or `100%` itself), but you can also place the `<video>` directly in the body.

Comment: Had to make a second container class which was the full width of the page, place the video in that and then the 1200px container class below the video. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy hacking!